# Create a rectangle with user location as centre of it

Tags: mysql, polygon, geospatial, spatial-index, mysql-spatial

I am trying fetch all points within 50 km radius of user location  from MySQL. For this I am using [spatial data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-spatial-data.html). I am trying to execute this query

```
select lat, lon from geom where
   MBRContains(
    GeomFromText('Polygon((46 -123, 48 -123, 48 -121, 46 -121, 46 -123))'),
    p
   );
```

For this I need to create a polygon(rectangle) which contains the current user geolocation. How can I build a polygon which contains the user co-ordinates and extends up to 50KM radius?